# Calculate cross-section area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, cross-section

Is there a way to calculate the area of a cross section (blue zone on the graph below)in QGIS without creating new layers ? Like a more complex version of the profile tool which would calculate this area from a digitized line?

[image]

Comment: What are those blue points exactly?

Comment: Simply filling to show the area I'd like to measure